# C#: Add User defined Properties into the Properties Tab in Windows form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am working in windows application. Is there any possibility to add user defined properties into the **Properties** Tab of the Visual Studio for my application.

[image]

ie: I have a `textbox` to which I want to add a property to the **Properties** Tab. The value to the property are "**Alphabet only**, **Number only**, **Alphabet and Special character**, **Number and special character**". When I select **Alphabet only** value, the text box has to allow only alphabets. How can we do this function?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you using the `PropertyGrid` control in your application and you want to add custom entries to it - or are you wanting to add properties for a control/component that you're building for consumption by other developers?

Comment: @Dai  i have a textbox where i want to add a property. The value to the properties are Alphabet only, Number only, Alphabet and Special character, Number and special character. When i select Alphabet only value, the text box has to allow only alphabets. How can we do this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited as per OP's further spec**

Yes.. You can able to do this by the sample below. When you create any user control/custom control, it has the option to add the property in properties window.

**C# Code - My User Control Class**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Globalization;

namespace TestSOF
{
    [ToolboxBitmap(typeof(DataGrid))]
    public partial class myTextBox : UserControl
    {
        TextBoxTypeSettings.Mode textBoxTypeSettings; //edited to support design time as well

        public myTextBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [Category("u4sSearchBox")]
        public TextBoxTypeSettings.Mode TextBoxType //edited to support design time as well
        {
            get
            {
                return this.textBoxTypeSettings;
            }

            set
            {
                this.textBoxTypeSettings = value;
            }
        }

        private void txtValue_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (textBoxTypeSettings) //edited to support design time as well
            {
                case TextBoxTypeSettings.Mode.AlphabetOnly:
                    e.Handled = !(char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back);
                    break;
                case TextBoxTypeSettings.Mode.NumberOnly:
                    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && (e.KeyChar != '.'))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }

                    // only allow one decimal point
                    if ((e.KeyChar == '.') && ((sender as TextBox).Text.IndexOf('.') > -1))
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    [TypeConverter(typeof(TextBoxTypeSettingsConverter))]
    public class TextBoxTypeSettings
    {
        private Mode _TextBoxMode;

        [Serializable]
        public enum Mode
        {
            NumberOnly,
            AlphabetOnly
        }

        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("u4sSearchBox")]
        [DefaultValue("")]
        [Description("Gets and sets the textbox's mode")]
        [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
        public Mode TextBoxMode
        {
            get
            {
                return _TextBoxMode;
            }
            set
            {
                _TextBoxMode = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public class TextBoxTypeSettingsConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
    {
        // This override prevents the PropertyGrid from  
        // displaying the full type name in the value cell. 
        public override object ConvertTo(
            ITypeDescriptorContext context,
            CultureInfo culture,
            object value,
            Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(string))
            {
                return "";
            }

            return base.ConvertTo(
                context,
                culture,
                value,
                destinationType);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. ill try now and reply you

Comment: @user2115618 See my edited answer.. that will help you better.

Comment: @user2115618 You can create a user control with `TextBox` and create browsable property with use of my sample.

Comment: bala Thank you for your code. It worked. but i have a doubt. I added a single property. I want my values to be displayed like a dropdown.

Comment: @user2115618 Please look into my edited code above. It has the option as dropdown (enum does the trick).

Comment: ya did it with enum

Comment: super i got it.Thank you.

Comment: @user2115618 I have edited the code which support the text box mode setup will work at design time as well (previous code doesn't support). Please refer the new edited code.. I have marked my changes as `//edited to support design time as well` thanks!